# Where are there English or German translations of either "Maaseh Torah" by R. Yehudah HaNasi or the "Maaseh Torah" by Vilna Gaon?

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, english, vilna-gaon, german

Where are there English or German translations of either "Maaseh Torah" by R. Yehudah HaNasi or the "Maaseh Torah" by Vilna Gaon?

I will also consider reading any of these in vowelled-Hebrew or in Hebrew with vowel-pointings.

I came across these two works at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midrash_Maaseh_Torah

Comment: They're neither translated, nor vowelized, but here are three HebrewBooks links to _Baraita Ma'aseh Torah_ : [one](http://hebrewbooks.org/20137), [two](http://hebrewbooks.org/33493) and [three](http://hebrewbooks.org/46799).

Comment: @TamirEvan - It even seems that the sefer isn't printed much anymore too.

Comment: @TamirEvan Thank you. The first link has 145 pages, whereas the 2nd and 3rd about 45 pages. My question: is the first link a different book than the 2nd and 3rd?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the book. I basically did some cursory web searching, and provided the links to assist anyone interested in taking it further. That said, from what I can see in first link's [first page](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20137&pgnum=1), there have been some additions made (starting at [p. 71](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20137&pgnum=71)), compared to the other editions. Also, in the text itself, the quotes were expanded, and their sources were cited.